# User table in database is changed, how to update session?

Tags: php, database, session, data-consistency

Currently when the user logs in my site, a (PHP) session is started and his database row is saved in his $_session. I do so because the size of user's data is small for now, and this way I do not have to ask the database for user's data every time I need it.

The problem is that, when I want to add or change something during the development and I touch the database, the session is not updated this way. The user have to logout and login again to update the session. This is good for now since the site is in development phase, but in production this is not desirable.

I wouldn't delete session files, because people are lazy and I would avoid to force them to re-login every time something change in database, and I do not want to reload the session every X minutes. My solution for now is a boolean column inside the user's table, false by default, that I set true when I change the database. Every time a session is continued, session data will be updated if that value becomes true. Anyway this way I have to do a (small) query every time an user continues a session. I do not know if this will be a problem in production.

Is there an alternative / better way to solve my problem?

Comment: if you're hitting the DB on every site hit to check if that "updated" field has changed, then you're basically saving almost next-to-nothing by caching the user data in the session file anyways. You'll still be hitting the db every time, so your design has gone from `n` to `n+1` queries.

Comment: is the user going to be the only one updating their own info or would there be outside data being stored in their session that you need to account for?

Comment: @MarcB: yes, that's because I'm not very convinced about my method :)

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey: what do you mean exactly with "outside" data?

Comment: @LucasMalor something that's not controlled by their actions, such as a reply to a post, and admin upgrades their account, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, one way to handle this would be every time a user row in the DB is updated that user's session data could be updated as well in PHP.

If it is not the user updating the records (such as an administrator changing a user's permissions) most likely you would want to force a logout of the user. If it is the user updating the records (such as changing information in their user profile) simply updating those values in the session variables may be enough.

In both of these cases you probably also want to provide a message to the user letting them know what happened.